# How to write, in an html page, an if else condition using serialport.on() response?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, node-serialport

I have the following server:

```
var express = require('express');       // include  express.js
var app = express();            // a local instance of it
// serial port initialization:
var SerialPort = require("serialport"), 
Readline = require('@serialport/parser-readline')   
var portName = process.argv[2];  
var portConfig = {baudRate: 9600};
// open the serial port:
var myPort = new SerialPort(portName, portConfig);

// look for return and newline at the end of each data packet:
var parser = myPort.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: '\n' }));
parser.on('data', console.log);

// get an analog reading from the serial port.
// This is a callback function for when the client requests /device/channel:
function getSensorReading(request, response) {
// the parameter after /device/ is the channel number:
var channel = request.params.channel;

// send the channel number out the serial port
//and wait for a response:
myPort.write(channel, function(){
    // when you get a response from the serial port,
    //write it out to the client:
    myPort.on('data', function(data) {
        // send the data and close the connection:
        response.end(data);
     });
   });
   }
 // start the server:
var server = app.listen(8080);
// start the listeners for GET requests:
app.use('/',express.static('public'));  
app.get('/device/:channel', getSensorReading);
```

Express serves an index.html page which is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.3.16 /p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.3.16/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var label, serverResponse;  // UI elements

    function setup() {          
        label = createSpan("Volume:");  // the label 
        label.position(10,20);              // position it
        serverResponse = createSpan();  // create a div for server responses
        serverResponse.position(label.width + 15, 20);      // position it
        getData();                              // make a request back to the server
    }

    // this function makes a call to the server:
    function getData(channel) {
        httpGet('/device/' + channel, update);
    }

    // update the page when the server responds:
    function update(data) {
        serverResponse.html(data);      // put the response in the span
        getData();                          // make another call to the server
    }
var flush1 = new Audio('1110.ogg');
var flush2 = new Audio('1115.ogg');
if(serverResponse == 'H') {
flush1.play();
}else{
flush2.play();
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
```

An Arduino sketch is providing 'H' an 'L'' to the server:

```
// digital pin 2 has a pushbutton attached to it. Give it a name:
int pushButton = 2;

 // the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
 void setup() {
// initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
Serial.begin(9600);
// make the pushbutton's pin an input:
pinMode(pushButton, INPUT);
```

}

```
// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
 void loop() {
 // read the input pin:
 int buttonState = digitalRead(pushButton);
 if (buttonState ==1)
 {
  // print out the state of the button:
  Serial.println('H');
  }else{ 
  // print out the state of the button:
 Serial.println('L');
 }
  delay(1);        // delay in between reads for stability
  }
```

I would like to get alternatively, depending on the letter H or L, the two sounds flush1 and flush2, whereas I get always flush2. I suppose the if condition is not right. What is the good format? Thanks for your help!